# How can I override autocomplete selected option in material UI components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

How can I override the selected options Css in autocomplete material UI, how it can be done with help of theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the selected options css through the customization points.

```js
...
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  option: {
    background: "white",
    "&:hover": {
      background: "red"
    },
    '&[aria-selected="true"]': {
      background: "blue"
    }
  }
}));

<Autocomplete
  ...
  classes={{
    option: classes.root
  }}
/>
```

## Live Demo

[image: Edit busy-swirles-42ooz]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  classes={{
    option: classes.root --> option
  }}
/>
```